# zsh completion - List files of certain mime type

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm writing an auto-completion script for an image viewer application. Is there a way to specify to list only files in the directory that are of a certain mime? I.e., all types of mime `image`.

What I am doing now:

`_arguments -C \
     ...  # Handle flags
    '*:images:_files -g "{*.jpg,*.png}"'`

Expanding this for all image types would be a little messy.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all images in the current directory:

```
file --mime-type * | awk '$2 ~ /application\//{ sub(":$","", $1); print $1 }'
```

but mimetype detection is kind of costly, so putting it into a completion function would be rather sluggish (especially if you run it on a large directory).